# Can't get Info Text (supports HTML) to display at checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I'm using Magento ver. 1.9.2.2 and have created a Flat Rate 2 shipping method which is an International Shipping function. The checkout selects this if the buyer is in one of the five countries listed in the Info Text (supports HTML) section. That Info Text however does not show up anywhere the shipping options are listed at checkout. Is this magento core or template specific? Would I have to add some code to display the Info Text (supports HTML) text or should magento be displaying this by default?

Admin Dashboard
[image]

Front end store view. One page checkout
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in a custom payment gateway.
In form.phtml of your module you must add the following code

```
<?php
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$code  = $store->getCode(); 
$instructions_block = Mage::getStoreConfig('YOUR-INSTRUCTION-FIELD',$code);

 if ($this->getInstructions()): ?>
<ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_<?php echo $this->getMethodCode() ?>" style="display:none;">
    <li>
        <div class="<?php echo $this->getMethodCode() ?>-instructions-content">
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($instructions_block)->toHtml(); ?>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```